# Correct Usage of Async in Typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await

What is the correct usage of the `async` keyword in typescript? My understanding is that it is to **only** allow the usage of `await` in a function body. Specifically,

```
async returnPromise() : Promise<any> {} 

export const interfaceFunction() = async () {
    return returnPromise();
}

// Usage in another module
const returnValue = await interfaceFunction();
```

Is the `interfaceFunction` explicitly required to be declared as `async` in this case? The code works with or without the async keyword (and the return type remains a `Promise` in both the cases as well).

Comment: It is a syntatic sugar of `Promise`. You don't need to declare `async` if your function return a `Promise`. You can directly `await` a `Promise` just like `await` an `async` function. If you declare your function `async`, you shouldn't return a `Promise`, otherwise you have to `await` twice. You should `return await returnPromise();` if you really need to use a `Promise` from other source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct!

> Is the `interfaceFunction` explicitly required to be declared as `async` in this case?

No. If you simply return a `Promise` you dont need to mark the method as `async`. Ony mark a method `async` if you want to `await` something within it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretending for a full answer.

but another option that `async` guarantee that function returns a promise, and make result than'able. It helps much when only part of function is awaitable. see example below.

```
function nPromice(){
    return Promise.resolve(2);
}
async function  n(){
    if(Math.random() > 0.5 ){
        return await nPromice(); 
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
n().then(x => console.log(x));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGACgJzgWxgZwKYAUAlAN4BQiliaeUIaS6WueAdDTnADYBuhATEQDcZAL5kAhjgCekRKEiwElMMXJVEMYAQCyEqAAt2EsABMsxRAD5EABlYBWRKQoaqNOg0QSA7hJhQyEzY+MRCiK6Uooh4XPiI6m6UHvRIAIwiGuLiUrIQ8uDQ8EjI-GqRmtp6hsZmFkTWdo7OiUkpXqgYIYTCEVkxcXgJFRrt6ZlU2WQKRcrIAMzEAFyIwSwAPGAgmABGeGhWrZW6+kZoJuaYljb2Ti5JybSpQV0sYX2TA-FHGgD0v2NEBkRu4nl41vh2HhOLxCGkiBUpmRVERWIY8KoAB6IAC8NggCBhbC4cAA5gRMURhEA)